# How to check if geo point lies close to a set of other geo points

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geo

I have a list of geo-points and radiuses around them

```
P1 = { lat1, lon1, rad1 }
P2 = { lat2, lon2, rad2 }
...
```

I can reorder this list and change representation in any way before hand.

My tasks is: given another point

```
Q = { latQ, lonQ }`
```

I need to find if `Q` lies close enough to at least one of `P`s, i.e. distance

```
d(Q, P[i]) < P[i].rad
```

I can just iterate over each point, calculate distance and compare it with `.rad`,  but there must be a more efficient way.

Comment: There are no more efficient ways, if you are dealing with billions of points you can use some approximation tricks. If this is not your case, the method you wrote is fine. It's just O(n)

Comment: @CristianTraìna Although I don't have billions of points, it's still interesting which approximation tricks do you mean?

Comment: for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root but you can also use other approximations based on well known math theorems (e.g. Taylor series)